# Using hittest and UIGestureRecognizer to determine which view to use

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, hittest

I have a UIImageView above a MapView.

I am currently able to draw lines on the UIImageView which is why i have TouchesBegan, TouchesMoved & TouchesEnded attached to it.

When i pinch however, i want the mapView which is underneath to zoom in and out and not the UIImageView. When i stop pinching i want to be able to draw on the UIImageView once again.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var myMapView: GMSMapView!
    myMapView.delegate = self

   lazy var canvasView: CanvasView = {
        var overlayView = CanvasView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: self.myMapView.frame.width, height: self.myMapView.frame.height))
        overlayView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        overlayView.delegate = self
        return overlayView
    }()

    class CanvasView: UIImageView {
        var lastPoint = CGPoint.zero

        override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            if let touch = touches.first {
                //Do something...
            }
        }
        override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
           if let touch = touches.first  {    
            }
        }
        override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            if let touch = touches.first  {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to use a pinchGesture. The issue is that its always triggered after all other events. I cannot use it before a hittest or a touchesMoved is triggered. I also can't seem to be able to pass the pinch data from a UIImageView to a MapView to zoom in and out appropriately.

```
      let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePinch))
        pinchGesture.delegate = self
        overlayView.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)

     @objc func handlePinch(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
        //Do something
    }
```

Since pinch gesture is triggered after a hittest i cant use it to determine which view to return in a hittest. Another way would be to determine how many fingers where used on screen. This does not work either however.

```
   override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
       var view = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
       if Int(event?.allTouches?.count ?? 0) > 1 {
           return nil
       }
       return view
    }
```

I can however detect how many fingers where used in a touchedBegan so i've tried to intercept the touch once it starts without any progress.

```
   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if Int(event?.allTouches?.count ?? 0) > 1 {
            self.canvasView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }
    }
```

How can this be achieved? I'm running out of ideas..

Comment: So the image view fully overlays the map view? And user either pinches or he is drawing? So he can not drag the map to look at other parts but he may pinch to zoom on it?

Comment: The ImageView fully overlaps the mapView. Optimally all two finger actions would be passed down to the mapview. Pan with two fingers and zoom. I thought id start with only zoom as the answer would most likely solve pan as well.

Answer (score 2):

My approach for this case would be to actually subclass your map view and forward touch events to the view that you draw to.

Since your map view needs to recognise the gesture it should be the view that responds to initial events. And once the gesture is recognised you will get a call to notify you that touches have been canceled.

I used the following to prototype it:

```
class MapViewDrawViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet private var mapView: ForwardingMapView?
    @IBOutlet private var canvasView: DrawnToView?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        mapView?.forwardsTouchEventsTo = canvasView
        canvasView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
    
}

class ForwardingMapView: GMSMapView {
    
    var forwardsTouchEventsTo: UIView?
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        forwardsTouchEventsTo?.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
        forwardsTouchEventsTo?.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        forwardsTouchEventsTo?.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    }
    
    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
        forwardsTouchEventsTo?.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
    }
    
}

class DrawnToView: UIView {
    
    private var paths: [[CGPoint]] = [] { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    private var currentPath: [CGPoint] = [] { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            currentPath = [touch.location(in: self)]
        }
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            currentPath.append(touch.location(in: self))
        }
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if currentPath.count > 1 { // At least 2 points
            paths.append(currentPath)
        }
        currentPath = []
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    }
    
    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // Canceled. Remove current path
        currentPath = []
        super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
    }
    
    private func drawPath(usingPoints points: [CGPoint], lineWidth: CGFloat = 3, color: UIColor? = nil) {
        color?.setStroke()
        
        if points.count > 1 {
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            path.move(to: points[0])
            for index in 1..<points.count {
                path.addLine(to: points[index])
            }
            path.lineWidth = lineWidth
            path.stroke()
        }
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        UIColor.blue.setStroke()
        paths.forEach { drawPath(usingPoints: $0) }
        drawPath(usingPoints: currentPath, color: .red)
    }
    
}
```

Obviously this code needs improvements when it comes to handling touch events and drawing. I would suggest not to call touch events (e.g. `touchesBegan`) on `forwardsTouchEventsTo` but rather create a protocol and use that to forward events through custom methods.

But it should nicely show the working solution. The touch events get called until they are canceled by the gesture recogniser. Even more the view that is drawing can remove the path that is being drawn due to one finger being recognised before the gesture.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i can't get it to work unfourtunately. The hittest needs to respond to a pinching event (before the hittest return a view ) in order to determine which view to return. By placing the pinch gesture on the map i would first need to return the mapview before it can even trigger. I cant get the sequence of actions correct so i'm not sure if i am on the correct track.

Comment: I wonder if i need to use a UIPinchrecognizer on both the UIView and MapView to change the globally stored value. Mapview also needs to use "shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer" for its inbuilt pinch method to work with a redcognizer simultaneously

Comment: @Redstain Maybe if you edit your question and add a bit more info on your requirements, what exactly do you need to achieve, it might be easier to suggest what exactly to use. Specifically I see you have a pinch gesture but map view should already contain a pinch functionality and then there are touch events that I am not sure what you are using them for.

Comment: I updated my question. I hope it becomes more clear now what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: @Redstain Sorry for all the questions but it matters a lot how things are meant to work. Anyway, try the updated answer and see if this takes you a step further.

Comment: I think you're current solution is a great way to solve it. I cant however get any response at all when placing touchesBegan, toucheMoved or TouchesEnded on a GMSMapView. I've tried all kinds of combinations without success. I've made sure to have isUserInteractionEnabled = true on view and superview. I've also tested mapView.settings.consumesGesturesInView = false. On a UIView or UIIMageView everything works well. Its only on a GMSMapView that i get no response.

Comment: I also dont really understand how a touchesBegun from a map would be able to determine if it is a pinch or not and responds accordingly. When i try to use touchesBegun it makes pinchgesture impossible to execute.

Comment: @Redstain so as soon as you override touch events the gesture recognisers stop working? That is not a good sign. Please triple-check that you are calling `super.touche...` on all of them correctly. It does work for "normal" views so I hope `GMSMapView` is not doing something evil.

Comment: Could not make it work by subclassing the map. I however solved it by creating a custom UIGesture attached to the map. Thank you for pointing me into the right direction!